# I keep getting the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int even though there are no lists or integers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've looked at numerous answers now but none apply to my issue which is that in my code I've made sure that none of the values are integers and that both the terms are arrays and not lists.

```
term = R1**2-Rsun**2*np.sin(lrad1)**2
lrad_new=([])
R_new=([])
for lrad_el,R_el,term_el in zip(lrad1,R1,term): 
    for i in range (0,178):
        if term_el >= 0:
            lrad_new.append(lrad1[i])
            R_new.append(R1[i])
np.asarray(R_new)
```

With this part I get no errors, however as soon as I place it in the next equation I get the TrackError:

```
term_new = R_new**2-Rsun**2*np.sin(lrad_new)**2
d = ((Rsun*np.cos(lrad_new))+np.sqrt(term_new))
```

The error I get is from the R_new, which is an array and contains no integers or negative numbers

Edit: I managed to fix the issue by making the new code: `R_new = np.asarray(R_new)` however I now get invalid values in my square root, but I though the element section of my code removed that issue.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input? Most variables are undefined

Comment: I've also attempted to just multiply the two R_news together and the error is now: 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Comment: lrad_1 contains each degrees from 90 to 270 (except for 180 and 181) and R1 contains distances except for the ones corresponding to 180 and 181 because the are either negative or zero

Comment: Here is an example of R_new: array([8.30557406, 8.30554512, 8.38219648, ..., 8.83122339, 8.78818846, 8.42113554]).

Comment: The expression `np.asarray(R_new)` doesn't modify `R_new` in place.  Did you mean to redefine `R_new` with `R_new = np.asarray(R_new)`?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that around the same time you wrote the comment, thank you anyways. I managed to resolve the issue by simplifying the loop and removing all the _el